# How to properly define ip_set_descriptors in wafregional CfnIPSet using Python

Tags: python, aws-cdk

Is there a usable example on how to set ip_set_descriptors for wafregional.CfnIPSet using Python)?

```
vpnWafRegionalIpSets=wafregional.CfnIPSet(
            self,
            "vpnWafRegionalIpSets",
            name="vpnWafRegionalIpSets",
            ip_set_descriptors=[A WORKING EXAMPLE]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just figured this out. You need to use the core.Token.as_any

Basically the .as_any method will take any object and wrap it in an IResolvable object which meets the spec.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_wafregional as waf
)

blocked_ips = waf.CfnIPSet(
    self, "BlockedIps",
    name="blocked_ips",
    ip_set_descriptors=[core.Token.as_any({"type": "IPV4", "value": "1.1.1.1/32"})]
        )
```